# Moseley's law and several series denoted by some letters

Tags: atomic-physics, x-rays

I read lectures about [Moseley's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moseley%27s_law) and understand something about x-rays, but I don't really understand what is the K, L, M, N series. There was K-alpha and beta. Please explain it to me in an easy way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In electron spectroscopy, you hit an atom with an electron beam. These electrons in the beam could have enough energy to free, through coulomb force, an electron in the core of the atom. This fact leaves the atom in a really excited state, but it quickly goes back to its fundamental state (when an outer electron goes into the emptied shell), emitting x rays. Analyzing these emitted rays, we can get the spectrum associated with that atom.

The first set of letters (K, L, M, N, ...) refers to the value of the principal quantum number that the emitted electron had when it was inside the core of the atom. Therefore:

- $K \rightarrow n=1$
- $L \rightarrow n=2$
- $M \rightarrow n=3$
- $N \rightarrow n=4$
- $O \rightarrow n=5$
- $P \rightarrow n=6$

Then, you have that, for each transition in which you have a hole in a certain $\tilde{n} $ level, this hole can be filled by every electron that has $n>\tilde{n} $. If the hole is in the $\tilde{n}=1$, for example, all the possible associated transitions (note that since they involve electrons with different starting energy, they will emit at a different frequency and therefore each one of them is related with a line on the spectrum) are called $K$. If you are referring to a transition in which this hole is filled by an $n=2$ electron, you will call it $K_α$, while for transitions involving an $n=3$ going to the level $n=1$ we have a $K_β$ transition, and so on.

Summing up, the big letter says which was the principal quantum number of the emitted electron, while the subscript letter is useful to put in order all the possible transitions associated with the same emitted electron.